# UMVUE for $e^{-\lambda}$

Tags: statistics, means

Let $X_1\dots,X_n$ be $Poisson(\lambda)$. Show that $$T= \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}$$ is an UMVUE for $e^{-\lambda}$

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$
it is a sufficient and complete statistic since the distribution belongs to the exponential family. But I don't know how to go on to show that $T$ is an UMVUE.
Any hint?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann–Scheffé_theorem

Comment: Yes, I'm. But I can't see how can I use it to solve the problem @AlexR.

Comment: that is, I don't see how to see that T is unbiased @AlexR.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/369931/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2294230/321264

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $Y = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \sim$ Poisson$(n\lambda)$, we can compute $E[T] = E\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^Y\right]$ directly,

\begin{eqnarray}
E[T] &=& E\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^Y\right]\\
&=& \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^k\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^k}{k!}\\
&=& e^{-n\lambda}\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(n\lambda\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\right)^k}{k!}}_{e^{n\lambda\frac{n-1}{n}}}\\
&=& e^{-n\lambda}e^{n\lambda\frac{n-1}{n}} \\
&=& e^{-\lambda}
\end{eqnarray}

So $T$ is unbiased. By Lehmann-Scheffe, it is UMVUE.

Comment: oh now i see it. Thanks a lot  @Flowsnake